2014 Escape - Bad wheel speed sensor and 2 aftermarket ones do not work
I've got a 2014 (no parking assist) Ford Escape SE with AWD
I was getting bad wheel sensor code on rear-left tire
Replace with aftermarket #1 and it still was throwing the code
I put the original "bad" one from the left on the right, but the good right one on the left, and now I've got an error on the rear right wheel sensor.
Cool, the problem is the sensor because it's followed the sensor when I moved it.
I got aftermarket #1 and aftermarket #2 (auto zone and orielly parts) and tried both of them on the right in turn, but still get errors.
When I look at the live data from the scanner while rolling down the driveway and the right rear is reporting 0 KMH while the other 3 look pretty consistent.
I guess the aftermarket sensors are no good for the Escape? I've ordered a motorcraft one to see if it works, but why don't the aftermarket ones work?
I have tried to test it, but it's active and I can't figure out how to test active sensors. Any idea how to do that?

Straight from a Ford Escape forum; https://www.fordescape.org/threads/abs-sensor-replaced-still-error.119235/

I've seen that - that's why I finally ordered an OEM sensor. Since the problem moved from left -> right when I moved the sensor from left->right, I think that rules out anything but the sensor (wiring, abs module, etc...) I have a bluetooth scanner that connects to my phone that is incredible, and was only $50. This lets me reset the codes and see real-time data.

Did you try flicking a magnet or flat blade screwdriver near the sensor (removed from the wheel hub but still electrically connected with ignition ON, to measure for signal output? Measured a known good sensor for comparison?

Sharing the answer here - the answer is use OEM sensors.
I tried 3 different non-OEM sensors and all reported nothing from the wheel.
As soon as I put the new Motorcraft sensor in it works fine.
